# Syntax complicated column in webgrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webgrid

The column that i want to accomplish has 3 possible outcomes.

- The paidDate is NOT empty --> just show the paiddate
- The paidDate is empty and the dueDate < NOW --> shows: paidDate / "with reference" / reference + add a class "green"
- The paidDate is empty and the dueDate > NOW  --> shows: paidDate / "with reference" / reference + add a class "red"

The code I'm using now doesn't recognize the 'item' and I probably have some syntax errors aswell. How should I build these if structures inside the razor page using WebGrid

### Codesample

```
grid.Column("", "To be paid before", 
                    (item) =>   if(item.paidDate != null)
                                {
                                    string(item.paidDate);
                                }
                                else{
                                    if(item.dueDate < @DateTime.Now)
                                    {
                                        /*CLASS RED*/
                                        String.Format("{0}\br Met referentie: \br {1}", item.dueDate, item.reference);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        /*CLASS GREEN*/
                                        String.Format("{0}\br Met referentie: \br {1}", item.dueDate, item.reference); 
                                    }),
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

> var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model.Modelname, rowsPerPage: 10,
>   canSort: false);

```
                            @grid.GetHtml(
                                           tableStyle: "GridActionStyle",
                                      htmlAttributes: new { id = "grdid" },
                                      headerStyle: "headerStyle",
                                      alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
                                    columns: grid.Columns(
                                    grid.Column(header: "To be paid before", format: (item) => paidDate != null ?  string(item.paidDate) :  String.Format("{0}\br Met referentie: \br {1}", item.dueDate, item.reference) : String.Format("{0}\br Met referentie: \br {1}", item.dueDate, item.reference) )
                                  )) }
                        }
```